# How can I display the first day in a df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

How can I display the first day in a dataframe?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Date': list(pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=50, freq='5D')) * 2, 'Value1': np.random.randint(0, 1000, 100),
     'Value2': np.random.randint(0, 1000, 100)})
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
#
mask = df.index.to_series().groupby([df.index.year,df.index.month]).\
       transform(lambda x: x.eq(x.min()))
df = df[mask]
print(df.head(10))
```

Also you can use `pd.Grouper()`:

```
mask = df.index.to_series().groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='YS'), pd.Grouper(freq='MS')]). \
    transform(lambda x: x.eq(x.min()))
```

```
            Value1  Value2
Date                      
2019-01-01     192     645
2019-02-05     923     610
2019-03-02     248     979
2019-04-01     167     672
2019-05-01     614     572
2019-06-05     718     618
2019-07-05     306     876
2019-08-04     210     624
2019-09-03     436     735
2019-01-01     938     417
```

Comment: I seem to get a Check for duplicates error when implementing this code

Comment: I rolled back the code to the first version where multiple rows with the same date can be selected.

Comment: Updated example, duplicates included

Comment: The code has been updated. Now the index is not affected, the order of the dates does not change

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, much appreciated!